# Industry benchmarks for site search

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, benchmarking

We have been asked to increase the performance of a clients site search. Before we start we would like to set benchmarks. I have asked the client if they are comfortable with enabling unanimous data sharing so we have access to industry benchmarks as I don't have control over this setting: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1011397 however it sounds like things have changed in the google analytics camp and these reports are only available via a newsletter now? Is this true?

Also, will these reports give me industry standards to compare my clients current search performance against? Or is there another service that has these baseline standards available?

Here's an example of the data we are interested in. This is our clients current search performance:

- Visits with Search: 772
- Total Unique Searches: 1,093
- Results Page Views/Search: 1.36
- % Search Exits: 56.45%
- % Search Refinements: 24.78%
- Time after Search: 00:01:40
- Search Depth: 0.59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at large ecommerce site, and I asked our AdWords rep about this, having recently wanted access to this kind of data myself.

He said that benchmarking was removed 3/15/11, at which point they were experimenting with a monthly newsletter format to deliver the same kind of data.

From what I've seen they *may* have done one newsletter before (quietly) retiring it completely. I never saw the newsletter, but I think I remember reading reports of people who did receive one.

Disappointing to know they had access to all that data, but pulled the plug on the program. I wonder if they killed it due to data integrity concerns--they can't guarantee correct tracking-code installations on all these sites opting in, so what is the data worth if it's of questionable quality. iono... just a total guess.

We used to use coremetrics here, and they had an opt-in benchmarking program. So if you know any other webmasters using Coremetrics, you could probably ask them to pull some benchmarking info.

We were able to get some benchmarking data from fireclick.com, but none of it (that I've seen anyways) covers on-site search. Mainly just top line metrics. :-/

So the search for benchmark data continues...